# Why can't the template type be inferred in this C++ function template?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, type-inference, apple-clang

Given the two function templates below:

```
template <typename T>
void gorp(T*, std::function<void(T*)>)
{
}

template <typename T>
void klop(T*, std::function<void()>)
{
}
```

The function `klop()` works as I expect, but `gorp()` does not:

```
int x = 3;

//fails: candidate template ignored: could not match 
//'function<void (type-parameter-0-0 *)>' against '(lambda at ...)
gorp( &x, [](int*){}); //1

//works
gorp<int>( &x, [](int*){}); //2

//fails: candidate template ignored: could not match 
//'function<void (type-parameter-0-0 *)>' against 'void (^)(int *)'
gorp( &x, ^(int*){}); //3

//works
gorp<int>( &x, ^(int*){}); //4

//works
klop( &x, [](){}); //5

//works
klop( &x, ^(){}); //6
```

Lines 3,4,6 use [clang blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html); lines 1,2,5 use [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Notice the calls to `klop()` have no problem inferring `T`, but I have to help out the calls to `gorp()`.

I'm at a loss. Shouldn't it be doubly easy for `gorp()` to figure out `T`?

Comment: `^(int*){}` - this is not C++. What language dialect do you use?

Comment: As I mention, `^(int*){}` are clang "blocks"--a many-years-old now extension to C/C++ in Apple's compiler. (They may even predate C++ lambdas.) They interoperate with std::function. Just ignore those lines if you're not familiar with Apple's tools.

Comment: If you want to use non-standard and non-portable extensions then that's your business (even though I really recommend against them), but please try to avoid it in your questions here. Unless the question is *specifically* about that extension, but then you need to explicitly state so and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau why would `T` be deduced as `int*` instead of `int`? `klop` doesn't work that way?

Comment: @273K see [Language Specification for Blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html) in clang's documentation.

Comment: @Mustang that's my point, `T` *wouldn't* be deduced as `int*`, as Someprogrammerdude had claimed. But I see his comment has been deleted.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry about the block distraction. They work and fail in exactly the same circumstances. Just ignore those lines please.

Comment: @Mustang "*Just ignore those lines*" - then you should [edit] the question to remove them altogether, since they are not relevant to the question and are just a distraction.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I explicitly wanted to demonstrate to those familiar that they succeed and fail in exactly the same way as lambdas. I'm simply inviting those not familiar that they are free to ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't infer the type `T` because you're not passing a `std::function`.  The type inference doesn't work if a conversion is also required.  This does work:

```
gorp(&x, std::function<void(int*)>([](int*) {}));
```

And so does this, using plain function pointers:

```
template <typename T>
void gorp(T*, void(*)(T*))
{
}

gorp(&x, +[](int*) {}); // + converts captureless lambda to function pointer
```

Or to support Clang "blocks":

```
template <typename T>
void gorp(T*, void(^)(T*))
{
}
```

And finally, to support all of the above with a single definition:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void gorp(T*, F&& f)
{
}
```

This can be more efficient than a definition taking `std::function` if the function is called many times, as `std::function` does carry some overhead.

Comment: Can you explain how the `+` trick works. I haven't seen that before. I always thought that `std::function` was the way to please all clients--but `F&&` is _much_ better

Comment: The `+` forces the lambda to be evaluated in an arithmetic context, which implicitly converts it to a pointer (to a function).

Answer (score 2):

If you must have `std::function`, you can inhibit type deduction for this argument:

```
template<typename T>
void gorp (T* t, std::function<void(std::type_identity_t<T*>)> func);

int x;
gorp(&x, [](int*){}); // works
```

However I would recommend

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void gorp(T* t, F&& f) requires(requires {f(t);})
{
    f(t);
}
```

This accepts everything the previous version accepts, and more, and does so more efficiently without conversion to `std::function`.

Comment: Thanks for the extra advice. I should have mentioned in the post that I can't use C++20. So for now, I'm just dropping the `requires` clause.